# How can I call DLL function using ctypes in python?

Tags: python, c++, dll, sdk, ctypes

I want to use DLL(C++) API with python.
The DLL file is [MMMReaderHighLevelAPI.dll](https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1c1i_FS1yk0XG6QS5pQ7LtLcgr7rQEGfB&export=download) from 3M SDK.

First, I want to make sure if I can connect to the 3M Page Reader by getting the status of it.
But, It does not work.

Here is my code that I have tried.

```
import ctypes

lib = ctypes.WinDLL(r"C:\Program Files\3M\3M Page Reader x64\3.3.3.10\Bin\MMMReaderHighLevelAPI.dll")
lib.MMMReader_GetState.argtypes = None
lib.MMMReader_GetState.restype = ctypes.c_char_p

call = lib.MMMReader_GetState()

print(call)
```

And I got `None` from the printing.

What should I try next?

[This is the function that I want to use.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jX264.jpg)

[3M Page Reader Programmers' Guide](https://www.scribd.com/document/589495943/Gemalto-3M-Page-Reader-Programmers-Guidev33)

Thank you very much for helping!

Comment: How is "ReaderState" defined? How are the "READER_..." constants defined?

Comment: Unless `ReaderState` is defined as `char*` your result type is likely wrong.

Comment: @MichaelButscher I have no idea how to do it. Would you guide me. I have added the '3M Page Programmers' Guide'. [link](https://www.scribd.com/document/589495943/Gemalto-3M-Page-Reader-Programmers-Guidev33)

Comment: @MarkTolonen I do not know what ReaderState is in the first place, and I do not know how to define it. Would you mind taking a minute to sample it in my code.  [link](https://www.scribd.com/document/589495943/Gemalto-3M-Page-Reader-Programmers-Guidev33)

Answer (score 1):

Based on the header file of the SDK from [here](https://github.com/tonymowers/pos_id_capture/blob/f1f68c839bc2e76d1f95d824ead16e8e894853ce/3M_SDK/1.2.1.2/SDK/Include/MMMReaderDataTypes.h#L1641) the following code should work (but wasn't tested).

The DLL you pointed to is 64 bit but in case you ever want to use a 32 bit variant, the calling convention of the DLL matters, so maybe "WinDLL" must  be replaced by "CDLL" then (64 bit has only one calling convention):

```
import ctypes

# Constants to compare to return value (may be incomplete, header file has more)
READER_NOT_INITIALISED = 0
READER_ENABLED = 1
READER_DISABLED = 2


lib = ctypes.WinDLL(r"C:\Program Files\3M\3M Page Reader x64\3.3.3.10\Bin\MMMReaderHighLevelAPI.dll")
lib.MMMReader_GetState.argtypes = None
lib.MMMReader_GetState.restype = ctypes.c_int

call = lib.MMMReader_GetState()

print(call)
```